# Opencv-ocl excutable with different hardwares?

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, opencl, gpgpu

I am working on **opencv-OCL library**. I use **AMD Radeon™ HD 7400M** Series GPU. I need few clarifications on it.

1) I downloaded the AMD SDK and **built opencv with opencl enbled** and made a basic c++ executable for face detect.
In this case, How my exe behaves in the following scenarios:
a. When it runs on '**OpenCL supported Intel or NVIDIA GPU**' based computers?
b. When it runs in a Computer **without OpenCL** supported GPU's?

2) Do I need to **make different opencv-ocl exe's** for different hardwares?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

1. Your exe should produce the same output whether running on an AMD, Nvidia or Intel GPU, although running times could vary substantially.  Any errors should be reported to the OpenCV developers.  One exception: floating point operations will produce slightly different results between different pieces of hardware, but these differences should be very small, i.e. close to the limit of the accuracy of float/double numbers.  I have no idea what happens when there aren't any OpenCL GPUs.
2. By different hardware, I assume AMD GPU vs. Nvidia GPU for example, not Mac vs. x86.  In this case you do not need to supply multiple executables.  That's the whole reason for using OpenCL, it hides the individual vendor's native interfaces (e.g. Nvidia CUDA) behind the OpenCL standard.